# Windows: add user group to file created by a specific process

Tags: windows, network-share, file-permissions, user-permissions, background-process

In our (mixed) Windows network we have a machine with a shared folder. This shared folder can be accessed by anyone belonging to the group `User`.

However, in this folder, there are files that are created by a specific background process on the local machine. These files lack the access rights for the group `User` - they only get `SYSTEM` and `Administrators` by default (as well es the user under which the process runs) when created by the process. Thus access to these files is denied to any of the network users.

The process runs under the main (system administrator) account on the machine.

Now, what would I have to do, so that files created by this process also automatically get the access rights for the group `User` when created? Is this something the process would have to do manually or can that be configured by the operating system?

Comment: Is the top level folder have inheritance enabled? What is the process that's running? Without knowing what it is we won't be able to really know why that's happening.

Comment: Yes, the top level folder inheritance is enabled. In the advanced section of the security tab of the shared folder (or any subfolder) I can see that the `User` group is there with the correct permissions and where it got inherited from.

Comment: How does Windows determine which permissions are added to a newly created file? The correct permissions (including the `User` group) are added when I simply create and save a text file with an editor for example - but files created from that specific background process only have `SYSTEM`, `Administrators` and the local user und which the process runs. Does it have anything to do with the permissions of the executable of the process for example?